# iPhone app versioning sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, versioning

I have made an iPhone app that uses a sqlite table. There is quite a lot of data in here, a table with items and also a table with favorites.

When I'm updating some database records, and rebuild the app, the changes aren't visible in the app, I have to remove the app and rebuild it...

By searching I figured out that the solution should be Versioning. But since I'm fairly new to the programming language, I have no clue where to start. I have heard things like pragma, user_version and stuff like that, but it's all Latin to me :-(.

Can anybody give me and idea how I can tackle this ?

Comment: are you using CoreDate to create your sqlite?

Comment: @geraldWilliam I have heard the term before but also no idea how to do this?

Comment: Core data is a very large topic. I recommend the apple documentation, Stanford university's cs193P (available for free on iTunes U)... Yeah, core data is built in to Xcode but you'll need to do some research.